# Error report - No more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle

While executing a procedure in a package,

```
BEGIN
  SYS_test.test_job.start(25698);
END;
```

I'm receiving below error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
  SYS_test.test_job.start(25698);
END;

Error report -
No more data to read from socket
```

I've searched on internet but I'm unable to solve this issue.

Could you please help why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: This is a generic error and there may be many reasons for it.  Possibly it's an Oracle bug.  So, look for a trace file in the `user_dump_dest` directory or an entry in the alert log (you may need your DBA to help you with this).